# There is an issue in the Stack Overflow editor

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editor

So if you write

`#include < iostream>` it will display iostream, BUT if you drop the space after "<" it simply ignore what ever you write after that.

I don't know if others are also facing this issue but I have checked it on Safari and Firefox and I am on mac.

Comment: Must... resist... urge... to... format... question...

Comment: @mmyers: why fight it?

Comment: because Joel, it's a boy learning, and you don't want to discourage the learning

Comment: Why fight it? Because formatting it destroys the meaning of the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`#include <iostream>` surround code by tick marks or

```
#include <iostream> // indent code by four spaces (8 after a list)
```

Source of the above:

```
`#include <iostream>` surround code by tick marks or

    #include <iostream> // indent code by four spaces (8 after a list)
```

There is a `?` on the upper-right of the editor that explains Markdown syntax:

http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/1382/edithelp.png

Comment: hmm, thanks man that was helpful.

Comment: +1 for answer, 6.5/10 for the drawing.

Comment: Indeed, my circle-foo is weak. What's missing?

Comment: There aren't any faces, construction equipment, or monsters in evidence.  A large spy or magnifying glass might have been appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put backticks around inline code: like `<iostream>` this. Or indent code blocks 4 spaces.

```
[space][space][space][space]Like <iostream> this

or Like `<iostream>`  this
```

If you just put in <iostream> it thinks you're using an HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, highlight the code and click on the little 101/010 icon above the text box.  Or click on that icon to put in the backticks and type in the middle.  That's how I did it for a long time.